# Python parse string as date without certain elements

Tags: python, date, strptime

I'm using `time.strptime` to parse a string as a date, but the string does not have a year associated with it. How can I add the current year to the date object?

Answer (score 2):

```
import time, datetime

def currentyear(atime):
    atime = tuple([datetime.datetime.now().year] + list(atime)[1:])
    return time.localtime(time.mktime(atime))

newtime = time.strptime("19 Jan", "%d %b")
newtime = currentyear(newtime)
print newtime
```

http://ideone.com/vI9S0

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> dt = time.strptime('12/31/' + str(datetime.datetime.now().year), '%d/%M/%Y')
>>> print dt
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=0, tm_min=31, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=12, tm_isdst=-1)
```

This is far from the only way to do it.